# where is an xorg-edgers nvidia install log?

Tags: log, xorg-edgers

Desiring to read it. It mentioned dell latitude and lenovo thinkpad as it scrolled on by.I have been having trouble with an nvidia card GT 630 and wondering if it is a genuine desktop gpu, or a fake with a mobile gpu  on a desktop card.

Answer (score 1):

The Nvidia driver from the packages from X.org edgers is managed by [DKMS](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Kernel/DkmsDriverPackage). As such the build log is in `/var/lib/dkms/${PACKAGE_NAME}/kernel-${KERNEL_VERSION}/log/make.log`.

Comment: It turns out the nvidia card is a fake chinese knockoff. http://www.sevenforums.com/hardware-devices/380413-fake-ebay-nvidia-card-sold-gt630-but-not.html I distinctly recall seeing something in linux installer talking about lenovo thinkpad and dell lattitude, something unusual when the driver was installing, but that log file does not show those messages. Installing the xorg-edgers 340 driver revealed that , but I cant find it again.